# RDP - Sharing shortcuts and/or toolbars

Tags: remote-desktop, shortcuts, toolbar

I often have to work across several virtual machines through RDP. I used to work with Terminals, and recently changed to mRemote NG.

As of now, I have a checklist that I run on each new VM I create, in order to populate the desktop with the shortcuts and apps that I use regularly. Then, I create a checkpoint and use that when I need to revert to a "clean" machine. However, it's not always practical, and the VMs I have to use are not always created by me so that checkpoint is not always available.

I know that I could use a template when creating the VM, but it doesn't solve the problem when I have to use VMs that I do not own.

Does anyone know of a way to setup one set of shortcuts/apps and be able to launch them on a remote desktop connection easily? Kind of like a toolbar that is present wherever I'm logged on...

Comment: Are these machines part of a domain?

Comment: @Keltari yup, they're all part of the same domain.

Comment: what kind of apps are you talking about?

Comment: Anything you could add to a shortcut, really. It could be a link to specific network folders that I use all the time, applications that don't require a local installation and can run from network folders such as Process Explorer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a folder on a network folder that only I have access to. The folder contains the shortcuts I need to reuse often, and may point to standalone apps on the same network share (such as Process Explorer). It also works with most windows features, like the control panel for instance.

Now, when I connect to a new computer, I can add this folder as a toolbar on the taskbar and instantly gain quick access to everything.

Not sure why i didn't think about it before. :) Still, building some sort of application/shortcut/setting deployment capability on a remote desktop application (like Terminals or mRemote NG) would be very interesting!